# Slick js half slide on the first slide

Tags: javascript, slider, slick.js

I'm trying to show half of the last slide and half of the first slide when a user sees the slider but when I try to slide to the next slide for a brief of second image from the 3rd slide appears.
What I'm doing is assigning a padding to the slick-list and remove it when the users slides to the next slide.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.slider').on("init", function(event, slick,direction ) {
    $( '.slick-list' ).addClass("half-slide");  
  });

  $('.slider').on("beforeChange", function(event, slick,direction ) {
    $( '.slick-list' ).removeClass("half-slide");
  });

  $('.slider').slick({
    dots: false,
    autoplay: false,
    infinite: false,
    speed: 500,
    slide: 'div',
    cssEase: 'linear'
  });

});
```

example fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/02q1xuzc/

Comment: CSS solution: https://jsfiddle.net/kc1r4muv/ - not tested thoroughly.